# Dart Native Library - Compile for Android and iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a library written in Dart that I'd like to use in both my Android and iOS applications.  The library contains mostly utility code as well as some of my business logic.  I am aware of Flutter, which seems to be the obvious choice, but since there isn't any kind of UI, I am not sure this will work very well.  I did some searching on Flutter and the results I got back were that it would be very difficult to use the library code without UI.

Is there a way to cross-compile my Dart code so it works on Android and iOS devices?

From this document (https://dart.dev/overview#platform), it looks like Dart Native can compile to ARM and ARM64 devices, but I cannot find any specific examples on how to compile this for Android/iOS.  The examples I find are for compiling to Linux ARM devices.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!